# New Relic lambda alert not firing

Tags: alerts, amazon-lambda, newrelic

We are using the out-of-the-box AWS integration for New Relic. We have an alert whose Critical Threshold is firing on lambda errors, but the alert is not sending to the alert channels.

Answer (score 0):

We found that you need to set the *Evaluation Offset* for the alert to 20 mins. You can set this value in the Alert Policy under Condition Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Evaluation offset.

Here is some more detail provided by NR support:

> When dealing with latent data and Cloud Integrations NRQL Alerting Conditions, one of the recommendations we advise is changing Evaluation offset. For Cloud Integrations such as AWS Lambda, in your case, we would recommend changing the Evaluation Offset to something greater than the polling frequency, which is usually 5 min be default.